# Vue.js / Lodash - Filter results if slug is in result.categories array

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm building out a product filtering system in WooCommerce using the WP API and I nearly have it working but I'm falling at the last hurdle.

Each product brings through its categories in an array, and each category is an array/object itself bringing `id`, `name` and `slug`. I'm currently trying to display only products which have a category `slug` that matches what's in the array the user has chosen. Not that a user can choose many.

Example product with a category that I want to filter by:
[image]

And here's how my Vue array (ageFilter) is getting the user's choices
[image]

I've tried to do

```
return _.orderBy(
    this.results.filter(result =>
        this.ageFilter.every(
            age => result.categories.every(category =>
                age === category.slug
            )
        )
    )
);
```

And whilst it returns true or false, it doesn't update the filtered products. Can someone point out how to do this correctly please?

Here's my full Vue code. I just want to take the array of choices the user has made, and loop through the product's categories and return any that have a `category.slug` that equals at least one of the user's choices.

```
<script>
    let products = <?php echo wp_remote_retrieve_body($products) ?>;
    
    function escapeRegExp(string) {
        return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
    }

    new Vue({
        el: "#allergenContainer",
        data: {
            allergenFilter: [],
            ageFilter: [],
            results: {},
        },
        created: function() {
            let self = this;
            self.results = products;
        },
        methods: {
            filteredResults: function() {
                if (this.allergenFilter && this.ageFilter == "") {
                    return _.orderBy(
                        this.results.filter(result =>
                            this.allergenFilter.every(
                                allergen => result.allergens.includes(allergen)
                            )
                        )
                    );
                } else if(this.ageFilter && this.allergenFilter == ""){
                    return _.orderBy(
                        this.results.filter(result =>
                            this.ageFilter.every(
                                age => result.categories.every(category =>
                                    age === category.slug
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    );
                } 
                else {
                    return _.orderBy(
                        this.results
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    });    
</script>
```

Edit:
Here's the template where `filteredResults` is being used, if needed:

```
<div v-for="result in filteredResults()" class="text-center"> 
    <div class="text-center">
        <a :href="result.permalink">
            <img :src="result.images[0].src" :alt="result.images[0].alt">
        </a>            
        <h2>{{result.name }}</h2>
        <h3 v-html="result.subtitle"></h3>
        <div class="p_more_div">
            <a :href="result.permalink">MORE INFO</a>
        </div>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: It's a mistake to define `results: {}`, it's supposed to be an array. You don't use `filteredResults` anywhere, and there's no template. And it needs to be a computed, it's impractical to keep it a method and call on every re-render.

Comment: @EstusFlask `results` is a JSON object, I am using `filteredResults` in the template it's just not included because that's not the issue, and the template isn't included either because there's no issue with that either. My issue solely lies with looping through the data and filtering it based off of a value of an array's key

Comment: You're using it like `this.results.filter`, so it's either not an object, or you use it incorrectly. Regarding your case, see the previous comment. Just use a computed

Comment: @EstusFlask Regardless of being a computed property or not, I still am unaware of how to properly filter my data - that's the question I'm asking

Comment: It's done the way you try to do this, more or less. The question doesn't say what exactly is the problem with your current attempt.